# Finding Maclaurin series for antiderivative, such that series satisfies some initial condition

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm given the Maclaurin series representation for some $f(x)$. Take, for example:

$$f(x) = \arctan{x^2}$$

I want now to determine the Maclaurin series for $F = \int f(0)$, such that $F(0) = c$. If you like, take $c = 0$, for example.

I'm not sure how to approach this. Need this be different for each $c$?

Comment: You mean $ f(0)=c=0 ?$

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Yes, apologies. I'll correct that.

Comment: $F=\int (f(0)$ makes no sense. I think you must mean the indefinite integral of $f$, usually written $\int f(x)dx$.

Answer (score 2):

Just integrate term by term, and then set the constant term to $c$. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

If near zero, we have
$$g'(x)=f(x)$$
$$g(0)=C$$
and
$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...a_nx^n(1+\epsilon(x))$$
$$=P_n(x)+x^n\epsilon(x)$$

then

$$g(x)=C+\int_0^xP_n(t)dt+x^{n+1}\epsilon(x)$$

for example
$$\cos(x)=1+\int_0^x(-\sin(t))dt$$
$$=1-\int_0^x(t-\frac{t^3}{6}+...)..$$